# Pass parameters between viewpager fragments

Tags: java, android

I have an activity that holds 2 fragments, one for list and one for detail. What I would like to do is, whenever a list item is clicked the related parameters will be sent to detail fragment. But I couldn't achieve it.

Here is activity:

```
public class ActivityMain extends ActionBarActivity{

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */

List<String> naviList = new ArrayList<String>();
ViewPager mViewPager;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout drawer;
ListView navList;
DrawerAdapter naviAdapter;
private static final int GRAVITY = Gravity.LEFT;
private static final String jsonURL = "";
List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
int check = -1, listCheck = 0;
Dialog d;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    //some methods (e.g. navi-drawer etc.)


}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.medicalendar_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
    }
    if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return ListFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Default");
            case 1:
                return DetailFragment.newInstance("DetailFragment, Detail");

            default:
                return ListFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Default");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}

private boolean version() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 11) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My List Fragment:

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;
List<String> naviList = new ArrayList<String>();
RelativeLayout loading;
EventsParser parser;
List<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

    parser = new EventsParser("");
    events = parser.getITEMS();
    list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new LazyAdapter(getActivity(), events);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    return v;
}

public static ListFragment newInstance(String text) {

    ListFragment f = new ListFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("msg", text);
    f.setArguments(b);

    return f;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
            //clicked item's data to pass next page.
            vp.setCurrentItem(1);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```

My Detail Fragment:

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

View v;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);



    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.d_map);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Navigating...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    return v;
}

public static DetailFragment newInstance(String text) {

    DetailFragment f = new DetailFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("msg", text);
    f.setArguments(b);
    return f;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

}
```

If you could help me I would be greatly appriciated.

Best,

Answer (score 1):

Basically you don't need ViewPager for navigating from one fragment to another. This should be achieved with replacing fragments using FragmentTransaction class, that will allow you to pass parameters in transaction. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html

If you still need ViewPager, you should set tag for each fragment with 
`fragment.setTag("detail_fragment");`
 and than your onListItemClick method should look like this:

```
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //get detail fragment instance by it's tag
            DetailFragment detail = (DetailFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("detail_fragment");
            detail.setParam("data"); //you should define this method in your detail fragment
            ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
            //clicked item's data to pass next page.
            vp.setCurrentItem(1);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.This is only used to send the parameters to my detail fragment, if I am not wrong. How can I grab those values in my detail fragment then?

Comment: Sorry sir, I could not get what you have meant here:
detail.setParam("data"); //you should define this method in your detail fragment

Comment: To pass any parameters to detail fragment, you need a reference to instance of fragment class. This is achieved with findFragmentByTag() method. Than you beed to create new method in your detail fragment class and call it from list fragment. I assumed this method could have setData() name with one string parameter. But you should create method whatever you need.